# What is the American version of the word ''tearaway''? (a young person who behaves in an uncontrolled way and is often causing trouble)

Tags: meaning, synonyms, american-english

I was looking for a word (a noun) that describes a young person/a teenager who is stubborn, acts recklessly, and likes to show off to draw people's attention (as they think it's cool).

I've found the word *tearaway*, which somehow fits the definition, and would like to know if there is a similar word which is commonly used in American English (besides the word *hellion*, as I think that doesn't wholly fit what I was looking for like the word *tearaway*)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119603/discussion-on-question-by-lala-what-is-the-american-version-of-the-word-tearaw).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Hooligan](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hooligan#Translations)

> "A person that causes trouble or violence"

Not necessarily specific to young people, but it doesn't necessarily imply illegal acts like *delinquent* which was my 2nd choice.

Comment: "Hooligan" isn't unknown in American English, but I get the sense it's much more common in British English.  In fact, as an American, my primary association with the word "hooligan" is "soccer hooligan".

Answer (score 21):

The word **delinquent** (basically standing for the legal term **juvenile delinquent**) is frequently used in US English in this sense.  The OED has the definition

> A person who commits an offence against the law or customary morality; a criminal, an offender. Now chiefly specifically: a person, especially a young person, who (persistently) commits minor crime or engages in antisocial behaviour.

Usage, from *The Prime of Miss Jean Brodie*:

> Joyce Emily Hammond, the very rich girl, their **delinquent,** who had been recently sent to Blaine as a last hope, because no other school, no  governess, could manage her.

Comment: JD ("Jay-Dee") is also often used colloquially, especially in communities of juvenile delinquents and those who manage them (social services).

Comment: *Juvenile delinquent*, to my British way of thinking is now very dated - and belongs to the 1960s. I doubt it is any longer politically correct - at least not the linking of *juvenile* and *delinquent* as are many things which link something derogatory with a particular group. Delinquency, it might be argued, is not restricted to young people,. Even a 70-year-old head of state, surely, is capable of acts of delinquency.

Comment: _‘Delinquent’_ implies a tendency to criminality, so seems rather stronger than _‘tearaway’_ (which is more about reckless high spirits).

Answer (score 10):

***Rebel*** is a common term for a person who resists authority, control, or convention. It can be used in a political context, but can also be used to describe a young person who flouts authority. The 1955 film *Rebel Without a Cause* uses the term in exactly this context, describing disaffected teenagers who act out against authority by engaging in reckless and dangerous acts.

Answer (score 7):

***Punk*** does come to mind, even though it may not be quite what you're looking for.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/punk

Comment: Punk wannabe.  Depends on the underlying intent.

Answer (score 6):

[Rascal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rascal), often modified as *young rascal*, might suffice. Note it would only really apply for minor offenses and is often used affectionately. From Merriam-Webster:

> 1 : a mean, unprincipled, or dishonest person
>
> 2 : a mischievous person or animal

Comment: I don't think anyone has used the term rascal in decades in common conversation.

Comment: I do every day - I teach 7th graders, and they can be rascally little wonders.

Answer (score 4):

> A young person who behaves in an uncontrolled way and is often causing trouble

Something that generally means the same thing, but not necessarily to the same degree, is **black sheep**.

> In the English language, black sheep is an idiom used to describe an odd or disreputable member of a group, especially within a family. The term stems from...
> ...
> The term has typically been given negative implications, implying waywardness.[1]
>
> In psychology, the black sheep effect refers to the tendency of group members to judge likeable ingroup members more positively and deviant ingroup members more negatively than comparable outgroup members.[2]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_sheep

This is often used to describe a family member, rather than a societal member, but it's sometimes used as a euphemism for someone who has gone to jail/prison or seems to be living a life headed for that end. However, there's a lot of context that goes into this, too. A well respected family might have a black sheep that's a rebel against the strict parents, as suggested by another Answer. On the flip side, a family that is disreputable might have a "black sheep" that's going to college, is a police officer, or something else that "goes against the grain" of the rest of the family.

This term also has a spectrum. Sometimes, but fairly rarely, it just means that someone hasn't gone into the family business or is doing "something different" than the rest of the family. Instead of someone being a doctor, like everyone else, they become a lawyer. With such a wide variety of situations, it's hard to pin down exactly how everyone uses it.

This doesn't just apply to a young person, either. There are plenty of adults and even senior citizens that could be called the black sheep of their family.

However, this term doesn't really apply to the body of your question.

> I was looking for a word (a noun) that describes a young person/a teenager who is stubborn, acts recklessly, and likes to show off to draw people's attention (as they think it's cool).

The other Answers have good examples of that.

Answer (score 3):

[Hothead](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hothead) is Wiktionary's suggestion, but implies more anger than recklessness.

[Hotdogger](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hotdogger) applies in the *narrow* context of certain sports or physical recreations.  It is generally a matter of pride and exuberance that doesn't imply any general criminality, but depending on the sport the risk of injury can be significant.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please quote the relevant portions (the definitions in this case) in your answer. See [*How to reference material written by others*](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: ?????  I linked the pages I read, per that guideline, and additionally what I wrote was not very similar at all to what those pages say.

Comment: @MikeSerfas - Who knows. Sometimes it seems like the mods here will tear people down just because they can.

Answer (score 3):

The word [Maverick](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/maverick) comes to mind.  Specifically:

> 2(b) a person pursuing rebellious, even potentially disruptive, policies or ideas:

It doesn’t specifically refer to a youth per se. The word can have both positive and negative connotations. Mavericks don’t follow rules or do what’s expected of them. Their behavior is often unpredictable and possibly even reckless or dangerous depending on the situation.

On a positive note, visionaries and trailblazers are sometimes called mavericks because they broke norms and defied expectations to do something extraordinary.

Answer (score 1):

### Bad Boy

Admittedly a gendered term, but *Bad Boy* does give you what you are looking for.

[Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=bad%20boy%20definition&rlz=1C1GCEB_enGB940&oq=bad%20boy%20def&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l3j0i22i30l3.9202j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) gives the definition:

> a man who does not conform to approved standards of behaviour, especially in a particular sphere of activity

[Dictionary.com's slang dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/bad-boy/) adds:

> Everyone loves a bad boy, as they say. A bad boy is a man who isn't afraid to break the rules. This rugged rebel, staring stoically off in the distance in his Aviators atop his Harley, is often seen as sexually desirable in popular media—though he'll probably break your heart if you date him. A bad boy can also refer to an "excellent specimen of something," like a car.

Comment: I think in this formulation, "bad" is used paradoxically, to refer approvingly to someone who breaks rules or standards - with a similar meaning to "maverick". The word "tearaway" is never used approvingly.

Answer (score 1):

[**Jagoff**](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/jagoff/) seems the closest to what you describe, although it tends to be used more on the East Coast.

The word sounds similar to the slur replacing the "g" sound with "ck"; however, it tends to describe someone who is self-absorbed and self-congratulating, especially when having accomplished something trivial.  The Oxford Dictionary makes mention of its use as far back as 1931 for "someone who steals petty items" (things no one else would want).  It is most often used to indicate a young person with no job, no purpose, and no clue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this for writing? If so, of the previous suggestions, "rebel" is probably the best. Delinquent is close but it implies criminal acts. If someone is speaking, the might say "He's a rebel." "Rebellious teen" or "Rebellious young person" would work if you are describing someone.

Comment: You should only use answers to directly answer the original question. Comments on other answers should use the comment fields below those answers.